# Trunk lid release

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, locks

I own a 2005 Ford Focus 4-door sedan. The button on the FOB and button on the dashboard to open the trunk no longer works. I can hear a click inside the car when I push the button. It started about 6 months ago. I have been using the key to open the trunk. I tried a few weeks ago and the push of the button (on both FOB and dash) would make the lock work when the trunk lid was open but not to open the trunk. The button worked until the lid was several inches above closing but stopped working when it was shut or almost shut. I tried again today and it only gives a click inside the car when you push the button.  Does anybody know how to fix this problem. The FOB works fine with the door locks.

Comment: If hearing a click, are you able to pull trunk up?

Comment: Is the latch located on the lid or mounted to the body?

Comment: Im having the same issue with my car can hear the clicking noises but if trunk is closed doesn't work. I dont know what to do? Did you fix your problem maybe you can help me..

Answer (score 2):

The click should be the latch solenoid firing so the signal should be fine I wouldn't think the FOB is the issue.

My bet is that the solenoid does not have enough power to disengage the latch try spraying some penetrating oil (WD-40 or similar) onto the latch claw and latch pin to see if that helps loosen it up.

If you don't have any penetrating oil you could use a small amount of grease or maybe even a small amount of cooking oil for the time being just to see if the lubrication helps. If it doesn't you may need a new solenoid/actuator.

Comment: WD-40 is not penetrating oil; quite the opposite...

Comment: Not exactly but it can be used as one if it is available. It might be better for this application because it will probably leave some oil for lubrication instead of evaporating rapidly.

Comment: ? Wikipedia specifically mentions WD-40 on its "[Penetrating Oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetrating_oil)" entry.

Comment: @Peter K. Yes but Wd-40 is designed to leave lubrication after use. Strict penetrating oils focus on having extreme penetrating effects but will evaporate pretty quickly.

Comment: WD stands for water displacer. WD-40's purpose is to get moisture out and keep it off of something; it makes a very bad penetrating oil for most places you want penetrating oil.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by checking Fuse#34 (20A) in the driver side underdash fusebox.

If that fuse is fine I'd investigate voltage @ the release solenoid itself. Looks like the white/green wire should get 12V when trunk pop is activated.

If that signal is good you may have a bad solenoid.

Comment: It sounds like he is getting the solenoid to pop but not when the trunk is almost closed, which would make me think more about worn wiring...

Comment: Certainly possible. I took "I can hear a click inside the car when I push the button" to mean the relay is clicking (ie coil activating). So we wonder if the relay is then outputting 12V thru it's contacts (87&30), is that signal making it to the solenoid (worn wiring as you say), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a 2003 Lincoln town car.  The trunk lid will not operate by the switch / button on the door or the key fob.

If you close the trunk manually and then disconnect the battery for a short period of time that the system (computer) will reset itself and the system will work.

This is only a quick fix though as the first couple of times I did this the reset worked for quite a while but now it only works a couple of times and goes dead again.